# Validate picture upload before create object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, multipartform-data

So i have a car class which have many photos.
And When creating a new car i need to ensure that the user did select a picture first. 
Here is the implementation.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :photos
end
```

and class photo:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :car

has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Here is a part of the car form:

```
  <%= form_for @car, :html => { multipart: true } do |f| %>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Modele</label>
                    <%= f.text_field :modele, placeholder: "Modele", class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">                            
                        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-lg"></i> Upload Photos 
                            <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
                        </span>
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </div>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: what are you trying to ask? will you please elaborate more?

Comment: The simplest thing would be to add a "validates presence of" validation to your model.  Shown here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-validate-attachment-file-size

```
require 'file_size_validator' 
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car

  validates :image, presence: true
end
```

This should do the trick

Happy Hacking

Comment: do you know what message you are getting?

Comment: THe in no message actually, only the room is created without the restriction :/